# Consistency of ZFC - foundation + ill-founded Mostowski Collapse

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to do exercises 20 & 21 from Kunen (1980) Chapter 4.

[book screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l04oq.png)

> 20. Assume $\operatorname{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ and show consistency of ZFC minus foundation plus the following modified Mostowski Collapsing Theorem:
>     If $R$ is an extensional relation on the set $A$, then $\langle A,R\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle M,\in\rangle$ for some transitive set $M$. Note that $R$ is *not* assumed to be well-founded.
> 21. Show that there is no finite subset of axioms $S\subset \text{ZFC}^-$ such that one can prove in $\text{ZFC}^-$ that “$R$ well-orders $A$” is absolute for transitive models of $S$.

Here's my current rough ideas:

20. Define $\mathbf{F}$ inductively for each level of $\mathbf{V}_\alpha$ while preserving some invariant for all extensional relations, then apply 18.
21. Suppose a finite set $S$ exists such that for all transitive models $M\vDash S$, “$R$ well-orders $A$” is absolute for $M$. Invoke 20 to get a concrete $M$ that also satisfies the modified Mostowski Collapse, work in $M$ to get a non-well-order that's well-ordered in $\mathbf{V}$.

Comment: Honestly I've always been confused why 21 gets an asterisk and 20 doesn't. For 20, I had to look up the original proof in Boffa's PhD thesis (which was very readable despite being poorly-xeroxed and in French) and I could only make cosmetic improvements on it. It's not immensely hard, but it is lengthy (3 pages in my relatively detailed write-up), and a bit of a leap from problems 18 and 19 though the ideas there are central. On the other hand, 21 seems like a straightforward corollary: construct a non-$\omega$-model of $S$ and take the "modified collapse" to get a violation.

Comment: (So I feel like I may be missing something and hope that someone comes through with an answer.)